# Port back to d6 $instance

Tags: entities, 6

I have this code that I am trying to get back to d6

```
 $field_name = variable_get('blogger_importer_node_tag_field', '');
 $instance = field_info_instance('node',$field_name,variable_get('blogger_importer_node_type', ''));
 if (module_exists('taxonomy') && $field_name && !$instance) {
 return drupal_set_message(t("Invalid tag fields selected for node type."), 'error');
 }
```

I am trying to figure out how to address the $instance area in this code as it was a new field variable in d7

I am just looking for kinda of a way to get it together I saw this maybe I can get somehting out of here http://drupal.org/node/728792